# The data types real and numeric are incompatible in the modulo operator

Tags: casting, sql-server-2012

I have following sql query:-

```
select b.LOGTIME, b.beam_current, b.beam_energy,
  case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_onoff=0 and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb ELSE 0 END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag2_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag2_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag2_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag3_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag3_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag4_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag4_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag4_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag5_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag5_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag5_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag6_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag6_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag6_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag7_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag7_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag7_rb ,
  CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag8_onoff='0' and a.logtime=c.logtime then c.st1_vs1_bag8_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag8_rb 

from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b  INNER JOIN (main_vacuum_analog c inner join main_vacuum_status a on c.logtime=a.logtime) ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME 
and  b.beam_current LIKE '%0' 
and (cast(b.beam_current as int) % 10.0 <= 0.01 OR b.beam_current % 10.0 >= 9.99)
and (cast(b.beam_current as int) >= 9.99) -- to set the lower limit of 9.99
and (cast(b.beam_current as int) <= 220.01)
and b.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'
```

But when I execute this query I get the following error message

**`The data types real and numeric are incompatible in the modulo operator.`**

How can I resolve it? I want to show only nearby values of beam_current from 10,20,30... up to 220.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer by:-

```
  (cast(cast(b.beam_current as decimal) % 10.0 as real) <= 0.01) 
and (cast(cast(b.beam_current as decimal)as real) >= 9.99) -- to set the lower limit of 9.99
and (cast(cast(b.beam_current as decimal)as real) <= 220.10)
 and b.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'
```

Comment: but now I want the nearest value,how to do that??